# Can't access JSON element in PHP

Tags: php, json, sqlite

I'm having problem acessing a JSON element after a sqlite query.

I have the following code:

```
$queryIdClient = "SELECT seq FROM sqlite_sequence WHERE name = 'clientes';";
$id;

if($result = $db->query($queryIdClient)) {
    $row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $row = json_encode($row);
    echo $row;
}
else {
    die($error);
}
```

The `echo $row` gives me {"seq" : "10"}.

I want to pass the value 10 to the $id variable. I've tried a lot of ways, but I can't get it to work.

Shouldn't it work with `$id = $row->seq;` ?

Comment: Is there a reason why you're passing it into `json_encode` in the first place?

Comment: `json_encode` returns a string.

Comment: what you get if `echo $row['seq']` just after `$row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);`

Comment: you just use `json_encode` instead of `json_decode` and there is no json in there. only sql result

Comment: Maybe looking for [array_flip](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-flip.php)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no need for the json_encode() there:

```
$queryIdClient = "SELECT seq FROM sqlite_sequence WHERE name = 'clientes';";
$id;

if($result = $db->query($queryIdClient)) {
    $row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    // $row = json_encode($row);
    $id = $row['seq'];
    echo $id;
}
else {
    die($error);
}
```